# Word document (.docx) editor on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, mono, ms-word, xamarin

I need to create a program with Mac OS X support, that involves a .docx document editor. Is there any ready-to-use components or will I need to develop it from scratch? Maybe some third-party (free or commercial) components? Mono (Xamarin) solution would be the best, however any other platform/language is ok too.

The editing capabilities that I need is editing text, changing fonts (color, size, etc.), inserting tables, images and graphics. Also the document need to be displayed in pages, and I need a programmatic interface to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevron NOV suite for Mono.Mac and Xamarin.Mac has a MS Word like component (DOCX, RTF, HTML, PDF and TXT), but is commercial. I work for this company.

Comment: Thanks! It would be ideal solution for my problem. But I cannot find MonoMac or Xamarin.Mac version on Nevron website. The only mention is "MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac hosts release coming soon" on the news page. Is it not released yet? Do you know when it will be released?

Comment: The main page is not updated yet, however you can download it from the downloads page - there is a separate download for Xamarin and Mono mac.

Comment: thank you! I tried and it seems to be exactly what I need. One question: is it possible to navigate in document in `NRichTextView` programmatically? I searched for and found `EnsureCaretVisible` method. But it doesn't fit my purpose, because I need to be able to specify exact position to navigate to.

Comment: You can use the following code:

richText.Content.Goto(ENTextDocumentPart.Line, 10);


to go to different document parts (paragraph, line, section etc.) or:

richTextView.Selection.MoveCaretTo(textPosition, false);
richTextView.EnsureCaretVisible();

to go to a specific position.